# How to install Java 11 through Jenkins Scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to install Java 11 using scripted pipeline of Jenkins, and I have tried the below ways

```
node('MySlaves'){
   stage('TestStage'){
        println "ALm Exporter Started"
        tool name: '11.0.12', type: 'jdk'
       }
}

node('MySlaves'){
   environment {
    JAVA_HOME = tool name: '11.0.12', type: 'jdk'
    }

tools { 
        jdk '11.0.12'
    }
```

All the above 3 methods didn't help and if I use `println "JAVA_HOME set : "+env.JAVA_HOME` then I am getting the value of JDK1.8. Can someone let me know how can I install Java 11 **(It is present in Custom tool)** in Scripted pipeline ?

Comment: jdk = tool name: '11.0.12'
    env.JAVA_HOME = "${jdk}"
By using this it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-controllers/how-to-specify-a-specific-jdk-in-pipeline) shows how to do it:

```
node {
  jdk = tool name: 'JDK17'
  env.JAVA_HOME = "${jdk}"

  echo "jdk installation path is: ${jdk}"
  [...]
}
```